# Control.SelectNextControl(...) in WinForms isn't working

Tags: winforms

I have three textboxes that each contain a two-digit part of an ATA code.  I want the UI to advance automagically to the next textbox when the Text is two digits long.  Easy enough, I thought:

```
private void txtATAChapter_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textbox == null) return;

    if (textbox.Text.Length == 2)
    { textbox.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl,true, true, true, true); } // breakpoint
}
```

... but it didn't work.  The breakpoint hits on `SelectNextControl` when the text length is right, but the focus doesn't change.  I've verified that all three of the textboxes have `TabStop == true` and sequential `TabOrder` numbers (`26`, `27` and `28`). The `ActiveControl` unsurprisingly is set as the currently focused `TextBox`.

I'm out of ideas for what should be a dead simple thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to set the next control on the `TextBox`. You need to set it on its container, so try:

```
textbox.Parent.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl,true, true, true, true);
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Just like the [second example in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yak83csz(v=vs.110).aspx) explains - if I had read it more closely.

Comment: This puzzled me too back in the day. The name of the method and the fact that it's on `Control` (instead of on `IContainerControl` or something or the likes) is a bit confusing. Compatibility reasons I guess